# How to use bidirectional pipes properly?

Tags: haskell-pipes

I am trying to use pipes to model a problem for which bidirectional `Proxy`  instances would be ideal. Basically, I have something like the following architecture:

```
api   logic
  |   ^
  |   | 
  v   | 
  A   A'
 layer 1
  B   B' 
  |   ^
  |   |
  v   |
 layer 2
```

so basically, I have `layer 1` which is a bidirectional transformer. The model is pull-based so I message stream transformations to be triggered by pulls from the `logic` component.

So I should have `layer1 :: Proxy A' A B' B m x`, the idea being that `layer1` pulls `A` from `api`, does some transformation `A -> B` then uses the `B'` from layer2, applies `B' -> A'` and pass it to the `logic`.

What is not clear is: I know how to `request` an `A` and respond a `B` but how do I produce the `A'` from the `B'`? There does not seem any combinator in the library that fits in here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types you need to be aware of: `Client`s can `request` but never `respond`, `Server`s can `respond` but never `request` and `Proxy` can do both.

The argument to `request`/`respond` is the value to send out, and the result you bind is the response/request, respectively. This makes intuitive sense for `request` (you bind the response), but it took a little while before I got it to click for `respond` (you bind out the *next* request). It makes your processing steps neat little recursive functions. (My initial instinct was to use `Control.Monad.forever`, which works well for unidirectional pipes but is the wrong tool here.)

The bit that gets confusing: because pipes themselves are synchronous, you need to get an initial value to pass around and kick things off. Either you pass it into `request` (making a pull pipeline which you compose with `(>~>)`) or you pass it into `respond` (making a push pipeline which you compose with `(>+>)`). Then you pass the initial value into the composed pipeline, giving you the `Effect m r` that can go to `runEffect`.

I've used a pull pipeline in the example below, because it fits your API-request metaphor. It implements this three-stage bidirectional pipeline:

```
+--------+  Yoken +-----------+  Token +--------+
|        |<-------|           |<-------|        |
| server |        | transform |        | client |
|        |------->|           |------->|        |
+--------+ String +-----------+ String +--------+
                               (shouty)
```

`client` generates request `Token`s and prints out responses. `transform` turns the `Token`s into `Yoken`s (hey, the keys are right next to each other) and passes them upstream. It also turns the response into a shout by upcasing and appending a `!`. `server` receives `Yoken`s and generates the requested number of `yo`s.

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Pipes.Core
import System.IO

data Token = Token Int
data Yoken = Yoken Int

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    -- We have to get an initial n outside the pipeline to kick things off.
    putStr "N? "
    n <- read <$> getLine
    runEffect $ server >+> transform >+> client $ Token n

-- The "server" generates a string of "yo"s based on the number inside the Yoken
server :: Monad m => Yoken -> Server Yoken String m a
server (Yoken n) = (respond . concat $ replicate n "yo") >>= server

-- A processing step just for the sake of having one, turn the Token into a 
-- Yoken, upcase the string, and append a "!".
transform :: Monad m => Token -> Proxy Yoken String Token String m a
transform (Token t) = do
    resp <- request $ Yoken t
    next <- respond $ map toUpper resp ++ "!"
    transform next

-- Clients request "yo"s, by sending `Token`s upstream.
client :: Token -> Client Token String IO a
client t = do
    resp <- request t
    n <- liftIO $ putStrLn resp *> putStr "N? " *> fmap read getLine
    client $ Token n
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for caring to answer my lonely question! I managed to find the answer myself thanks to http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-2.3.0/docs/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html